# AJAX Call to PHP file: return value is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a simple ajax call:

```
function init() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "./myFolder/user.php",
        data: {
            action: "init"
        },
        type: "post",
        success: function (output) {
            console.log("Success");
            console.log("Output: " + output);
        }
    });
}
```

The PHP `init` method gets called and simply should return some json data:

```
function init() {
    $arr = array(
        array(
            "region" => "valore",
            "price" => "valore2"
        ),
        array(
            "region" => "valore",
            "price" => "valore2"
        ),
        array(
            "region" => "valore",
            "price" => "valore2"
        )
    );

    return json_encode($arr);
}
```

but my console says:

```
Success
Output:
```

So the output variable is empty. Where is my json data?

Comment: Do you actually output the data given by `init()` somewhere, or do you just return it?

Comment: Are you sure the `init()` function is getting called? I mean, you know that writing `action: "init"` in the javascript doesn't call the php function, right? Echoing the encoded array should be enough.

Comment: `echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: the solution of @Maxxi is correct. echo instead of return. but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `user.php` page you need to do :-

```
function init() {
        $arr = array(
            array(
                "region" => "valore",
                "price" => "valore2"
            ),
            array(
                "region" => "valore",
                "price" => "valore2"
            ),
            array(
                "region" => "valore",
                "price" => "valore2"
            )
        );

        echo  json_encode($arr);
    }
```

Comment: why should i need that? i call my init method asynchronosly using javascript. so why should i call it in my php file? that makes no sense.

Comment: yes. now it is working. can you explain why echo is working and return isnt?

Comment: proper definition is given in this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107144/difference-between-php-echo-and-return-in-terms-of-a-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score -2):

u should have in your user.php somthing like this:

```
die(init());
```

Comment: sorry... but... what?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? your php script should not just generate data but OUTPUT it. with echo, die, etc