# Working with multidimensional array in AJAX response

Tags: jquery

I do an AXAX post like so:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'formprocess.php', 
    data: {formtype: 'load_all_names'},
    dataType : 'json',
    encode : true
}).done(function(data) {


});
```

The PHP page it posts to is formprocess.php, which looks like:

```
$return = array();

$return['names'][0]['name'] = 'Tom';
$return['names'][0]['age'] = 20;
$return['names'][1]['name'] = 'Dick';
$return['names'][1]['age'] = 30;
$return['names'][2]['name'] = 'Harry';
$return['names'][2]['age'] = 40;

echo json_encode($return);
```

Now, how do I get, for example, Harry's age?

```
$.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'formprocess.php', 
    data: {formtype: 'load_all_designs'},
    dataType : 'json',
    encode : true
}).done(function(data) {

   alert(data.names[2].age); // Not working

});
```

- EDIT: My formprocess.php file does echo the array.

Comment: Try doing `console.log(data)` to see what you have, I'm guessing nothing as PHP's `return` doesn't output anything, you need `echo json_encode($return);`

Comment: You need `echo json_encode($return)` ... `echo` is what you want [when you are using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107144/difference-between-php-echo-and-return-in-terms-of-a-jquery-ajax-call)